# time value into database php syntax conversion error

Tags: php, sql, time

So I am working on a way of transforming a timer which appears like this in HTML:

00:00:00

in hh/mm/ss - and I want to input it into my database but with it just as an integer value depicting the total seconds driven.

This is the method I have used to do this, where 'timedrive' is the form holding the time value, eg: "02:21:51".

```
$length = mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['timeDrive']);

        $parts = explode(":", $length);

        $totalSeconds = parts[0] * 3600 + parts[1] * 60 + parts[2];
```

Nevertheless it is not working for what ever reason, I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/benjamin/public_html/elog/iframe/addtodatabase.php on line 17
```

this is line 17:

```
$totalSeconds = parts[0] * 3600 + parts[1] * 60 + parts[2];
```

Thanks heaps for the help with this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `$` before your variable references:

```
$totalSeconds = $parts[0] * 3600 + $parts[1] * 60 + $parts[2];
```